# create an object[ ] from 2 list in java

Tags: java

I have 2 list, I want to create an object[]from this 2 list:

```
List<Object[]> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    l1.add(new Object[] { "itemP1", "child1", });
    l1.add(new Object[] { "itemP2", "child2", });
    l1.add(new Object[] { "itemP3", "child3", });
    List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    l2.add("item");
    final Object[] inventory = new Object[] { "item", new Object[] { "itemP1", "child1", },
            new Object[] { "itemP2", "child2", }, new Object[] { "itemP3", "child3", }, };
```

but by looping l1 and l2 not manually . have any idea please?

Comment: Do you mean `ArrayList.addAll()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
List<Object> finalList= new ArrayList<Object>(l1);
finalList.addAll(l2);
Object[] finalArray = finalList.toArray(new Object[finalList.size()]);
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Dragos

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class OBJ {
        public static void main(String[] args) {        
            List<Object[]> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
            l1.add(new Object[] { "itemP1", "child1", });
            l1.add(new Object[] { "itemP2", "child2", });
            l1.add(new Object[] { "itemP3", "child3", });
            List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
            l2.add("item");
            final Object[] inventory = new Object[l2.size()+l1.size()]; // calculate size
            for(int i = 0; i<l2.size();i++){     // add elements of l2
                inventory[i]=l2.get(i);
            }
            for(int i = l2.size(); i<l2.size()+l1.size();i++){    //add elements of l1
                inventory[i]=l1.get(i-l2.size());
            }
        }         
    }
```